# data arrangement in split split plot design

Tags: plot, split

I am a master's student from india. Presently doing research on split split plot design and its analysis. When I analysed  a split split plot design anova example as given in the book STATISTICS: AN INTRODUCTION USING R by M.J. Crawley (Chapter 9,split plot experiments,split yield example) using the excel data given in "http://www.bio.ic.ac.uk/research/crawley/statistics" , excel sheet name is split yield.The anova is run as per the commands given in the text

splityield<-read.table(“c:\temp\splityield.txt”,header=T)

attach(splityield)

names(splityield)

(model<-aov(yield~irrigation*density*fertilizer+Error(block/irrigation/density/fertilizer))

summary(model)
I got the same anova table given in the text using the above programme .Then i changed the levels of irrigation from control,irrigated to 0,1 (used codes of 0,1 instead of text control and irrigation)in the irrigation column of excel sheet.like wise i changed the levels of density and fertilizer to digits or codes(0,1,2).After running the same r programme i am getting an entirely different anova table.why it is so happening.my second question is whether any change in r programme will occur if the factors under the consideration is fixed or random.Thanking you in advance.

Comment: If you change irrigation from text to numeric, you MUST be sure that R is treating the new variable as a factor, not as a numeric variable.  For example:
irrig = factor(irrig)
If you do not make sure that irrigation is a factor, then the mixed model might be treating it like a numeric covariate instead of a factor.